# Rails 3.1 Asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am fairly new to rails and Jquery and am looking for some guidance on which libraries I should keep and which one I don't need.

Anyway currently I have the following in my javascript library

```
admin.js.coffee 
application.js  
bootstrap-alert.js  
calendar.js 
documents.js.coffee 
folders.js.coffee   
fullcalendar.js
gcal.js 
jquery-1.7.min.js   
jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js   
jquery-ui.js    
jquery-ui.min.js    
jquery.bookshelfslider.js   
jquery.bookshelfslider.min.js   
jquery.easing.1.3.js    
jquery.js   
jquery.rest.js  
jquery.ticker.js    
jquery_ujs.js   
rails.js    
site.js 
stickybar.jquery.min.js
stickysidebar.jquery.js 
turn.js
```

My application.js file looks like this

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Is there anything anyone can see that would cause me any issues? if I am calling a library within application.js, do I need the library in my Javascript directory?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rails.js` is the legacy name of `jquery_ujs.js`. You can remove the former.

Also, you don't need to store the following file in the javascripts directory

```
jquery-1.7.min.js   
jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js   
jquery-ui.js    
jquery-ui.min.js    
jquery.js
rails.js
```

Simply install [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) gem.

For more information, here's the [Rails 3.1 asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: So //= require jquery-ui gives me all the functionality of the jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js file?

Comment: Wow, that makes things quite simple. With the way i have things, would that cause any issues with speed, i.e. calling the library twice?